# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle

I am using gradle6.8.1 and jdk15 to construct my Spring microservice project.  While running my project test I am getting these errors:

```
Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is
   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap.addAll(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[])'

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is 
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap.addAll(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[])'
```

I don't have idea about this error, but it was working in other machines.
So, I have checked with various versions of gradle and java sdk but no use.
And I also tried after clear gradle cache but its not working.

Comment: Vast majority of `NoSuchMethodError`s are coming for mismatched jar versions on classpath. inpsect your classpath for presence of jax-rs related jars and see if all versions are in sync.

Comment: The problem is that you are compiling against one version of `javax.ws.rs.*` and using a different version at runtime.  In your case, you appear to have an issue with the way that you **deploy** the application and its dependencies ... to your test platform.